# Tricky Apache redirect/hack wanted to redirect site.com/dir/ to site.com/dir/foo (where foo is the only file in /dir/ (but its not always named foo))

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

There is a section of my site that's setup for easy posting/sharing of files, each time a file is uploaded it's placed within it's own directory, examples:

- http://c.sente.cc/78at/stackoverflow.html
- http://c.sente.cc/XEEA/free

I'm curious if Apache can be configured such that any requests to a file's parent directory will automatically be redirected to the file itself:

```
http://c.sente.cc/XEEA/  -> http://c.sente.cc/XEEA/free
http://c.sente.cc/78at -> http://c.sente.cc/78at/stackoverflow.html
```

I know an individual .htaccess file could be created within each directory which would explicitly make the redirect but I'd rather not have a million .htaccess files for each of my million uploaded files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *think* this can be done with stock Apache. `mod_rewrite` is the tool you would normally use, but to the best of my knowledge it doesn't have any facilities for listing files in a directory.

You could write a little shell script to do the redirect (ex, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
base_dir="/var/www/uploads"
cd "$base_dir"
requested="${QUERY_STRING//../}"
requested="${requested#/}"
echo "301 Moved permanently"
echo "Location: /$(ls -1 "requested" | head -n 1)"
```

but that's just a quick hack, and probably doesn't work), then use a `mod_rewrite` rule like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule (.*) /cgi-bin/redirect?$1
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm also pretty sure that stock Apache can't do the redirect either.  A slightly different Apache-only solution would be (if it worked) to set `DirectoryIndex foo` for whatever `foo` is, the issue is wildcards aren't accepted.  Manually setting `DirectoryIndex problem9.py` at http://c.sente.cc/9684/ works (http://c.sente.cc/9684/problem9.py) but doing this on a per file basis is garbage.  I might end up going with what you suggested, I just wanted to an Apache-only solution for-no-good-reason really.  Thank you.